# sudo in php exec() return exit code 1

Tags: php, sudo, sudoers

I want to run "sudo whoami" command in php script.

I have added next line into /etc/sudoers

> apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/whoami

and executed the script

```
$result = exec("sudo whoami", $output, $return_var);
```

$result is empty. $return_var == 1

Terminal command

```
su -s /bin/bash apache -c "sudo whoami"
```

returns "root".

PHP 5.6.38

CentOS 7.5.1804

Comment: Why "sudo"? `whoami` is not a protected command.

Comment: Just an example. My goal is execute exec("sudo myscript.sh")

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding next lines into httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
  LimitUIDRange 0 6000
  LimitGIDRange 0 6000
</IfModule>
```