# PHP exec not working with sudo in Apache2 but in CLI

Tags: php, apache, unix, debian

I want to execute a command (systemctl) from PHP using exec, but it just won't work.

My PHP looks like this:

```
exec("/usr/bin/sudo /var/www/my-systemctl stop my-service", $out, $ret);
echo("<p>".$ret."</p>");
```

It doesn't matter if I use `/usr/bin/sudo` or just `sudo`. $ret is always 1

The script my-systemctl just contains `systemctl $@` but it doesn't work with `/bin/systemctl` either.

If I execute the above exec-command from the php-CLI with `sudo -u www-data php -a` it works perfectly fine. Other exec-commands without sudo work fine in CLI and apache.

I edited sudoers and added the following:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/my-systemctl stop my-service
```

I really have no clue anymore and my google searches only give me advices like editing sudoers or checking php.ini for disallowed exec... But exec is not disabled for me.

I'm running php 7.4 with apache2 on Debian 10 as www-data

Thank you very much in advance, I really need some help here :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here:
[sudo-in-php-exec-return-exit-code-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60074822/sudo-in-php-exec-return-exit-code-1?rq=1)

I just needed to set correct UID and GID limits using:

```
<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
  LimitUIDRange 0 6000
  LimitGIDRange 0 6000
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I had a similar problem but i wanted to run different commands when a user clicked a button on my website, my issue was the command required root or sudo to run, I will post my answer in full below - hope it helps you and any other curious visitors.